# Complicated width Calculation in Scss

Tags: html, css, math, sass

I tried to make a very dynamic angular2 component, for printing user lists. The problem is, that I am not the best in math. Now I'm trying to understand what is wrong with my math calculation.

I have set up a pen to demonstrate the problem:

http://codepen.io/BamiGorengo/pen/rjWmao

I give every `li` a padding, the first and last in row I reset to padding outer `0`. So I need to recalculate the missing padding, that I remove. That every element got exactly same size and use 100% of the content width.

Comment: Do you have any particular browser support? Can flexbox be used or do you want it this way?

Comment: i get all the time problems with flex box... i want it very dynamic. that i can enter only count of rows and space between items without outer padding. maybe only my flexbox skills are to bad. if you can do this perfectly with flex box, then flexbox is cool to.

Comment: I wrote you both solution that work exactly the same

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions

## Final (update):

Here is a "hacky" solution by my means, but it does what you want:

We need to use `calc` because we will be mixing % and px's.

Firstly, we need to change from `padding` to `margin` so the width inside will stay the same when we remove the spacing for the last and first item.

Now we need to include the margin in width calculation but it's not as simple as

`$width - $spacing * 2`

Because we are removing the margins. So here is the formula:

```
width: calc(#{$userWidth} - #{(($spaceBetweenUserList * 2) - ($spaceBetweenUserList/4))});
```

This will work for 8 elements but not for all because we need to factor in how many elements there are, so the final **(complicated)** formula:

```
width: calc(#{$userWidth} - #{((($userEachRow * $spaceBetweenUserList * 2)) - ($spaceBetweenUserList * 2))/$userEachRow});
```

[Final working demo](http://codepen.io/rema/pen/apBqNr)

## Floats (original)

The only mistake you made with the floats is the actual width of a `li` element. You wrote this:

`width: calc(#{$userWidth} + #{$spaceBetweenUserList / 2});`

You don't need the `$spaceBetweenUserList` because it is padding and **CSS Box Model** says that padding is "inside the box".

So an actual fix is just use the width `width: $userWidth;`

And finally you achieve the end to end effect add `margin: 0 (-1) * $spaceBetweenUserList`. This will go negatively left and right, pulling the the existing padding on the ends.

## Flexbox

More elegant solution if you ask me, because you "don't" need breakpoints and all that. Also much simpler

```
ul.flexbox {
  margin: 0 (-1) * $spaceBetweenUserList;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  li {
    flex: 0 0 $userWidth;
    padding: 0 $spaceBetweenUserList;
  }
}
```

Browser support is really good over 97% prefixed.

### Demo

Here are both demos
[Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/rema/pen/YNpVLN)

Comment: Thanks but your codepen is still buggy ;) http://imgur.com/a/UEN58 check this screenshot the boxes are diffrent big and on right side is a free space when you change the rowcount

Comment: Sorry I will fix it now

Comment: and the flexbox didnt work to, because when i reset the outer elements outer paddings to 0, then the boxes are diffrent sized.

Comment: Sorry, I see your problem Pen updated. I will write it now

Comment: @Budi Is it ok now

Comment: Thanks alot for your time! but this is a dirty solution from bootstraps. please remove from the class .wrapper the width 80%, let it be 100%, then you will see a bottom scrollbar. the only clean solution is a perfect math calculation like i tryed to do. =) but the best solution is the complicatest one.

Comment: @Budi I know this but this is the only way of achieving something like. It would be impossible to do the thing you are asking, because You can't have a fixed (defined)  width and a fixed padding but remove the padding on some elements, as soon as you do that the element with removed padding will be bigger.

You need to removed the predefined padding so the elements could be spaces freely

Comment: WOW! You made it! very very awesome job! thanks alot for the worlds cleanest solution ever =)

Comment: I made a mixin with your genius code: http://codepen.io/BamiGorengo/pen/PWWPwR now every element got a margin bottom. the last elements to. im thinking but i am not sure what is the cleanest way to remove the margin-bottom's from elements in last row. i dont find any better way then javascript. Ypu think, there is any solution, with sass only? but we cant get the li count.

Comment: @Budi There is a way but I won't work for all cases. For example you cant get a range of elements in CSS using nth-child but the problem is you can't count the number of rows. If you have 12 elements and the grid is 6 you will have 2 but if the grid is 4 then it's 3 rows. You can do this in SASS only if you provide number of elements to the mixin, but that will break the dynamic part...

Comment: @Budi the range with nth-child I am talking about goes like this:
:nth-child(n+#{$grids+1}):nth-child(-n+#{$grids*2}) {}

Comment: incredible.. Are you a Math Professor? :) You are right, it work only when we got every row full... hmm okay i didnt got any better idea. maybe its time to accept, that there is no way to do this totaly dynamicly.

Comment: I tryed to use your code (our mixin on: http://codepen.io/rema/pen/BpWgpJ) to do this: http://image.prntscr.com/image/0a4195483d0c4c8ebffb101d7bef8101.png But i dont got any idea, how i can made this with our mixin, you think this is possible? i made it now fast without the mixin, dirty and not responsive. Tryed now for about 2 days, to find a clean solution. but you know my bad logical math skills :D By the way, i create a simple small lib: https://git.upperyard.de/Budi/scss-elements